# Improve the speed of for loop for readline of very big files

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to improve the speed of my for loop for reading lines from very big files. I have two files, I am taking information from first file line by line in a `for` loop and matching these each to lines from a second file through an `if` statement. Since both the files have millions of lines, this is taking too long.

I am posting my code here; How can I improve the loop statement to increase the speed of execution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#open file1
f1 = open("../../Reapeat_analysis/FIMO/fimo_out/fimo.gff",'r')
#open file2
f2 = open("../BS_Forward.fastq_bismark_pe.CX_report.txt",'r')

f1.seek(0)
f2.seek(0)

#open and save output
fOut = open("output_sample_CG+.txt",'w')

#Reading file1 lines in for loop
for line1 in f1:
    line1 = line1.split('\t')
    s1 = int(line1[3])
    s2 = int(line1[4])
    s0 = str(line1[0])
    count = 0
    percent = 0
    lt = []

    #Reading file2 lines for each file1 line
    for line2 in f2:
        line2 = line2.split("\t")

        #Matching desired condition
        if (s0 == str(line2[0])) and (s1 <= int(line2[1]) <= s2) and (str(line2[5])=="CG") and (str(line2[2])=="+"):
            lt.append(line2)
            count = count + 1

    #saving each matched conditions
    fOut.write(str(s1) + "-" + str(s2) + ":" + str(s0) + "\t" + str(count) + "\t" + str(lt))
    f2.seek(0)
fOut.close()
```

Between 0 and 100 lines of the `f2` file match the `(str(line2[5])=="CG") and (str(line2[2])=="+")` filter.

Comment: Yes, looping over both files in a nested loop will take N * M time, with disk IO being the bottleneck. Don't do that. Find a way of caching the information from at least one file in memory, or use a database.

Comment: you have a O(n^2) complexity ... couldnt you first process one file into some kind of lookup dict?  yeah what @MartijnPieters said :P

Comment: How many rows in f2 actually matter, so have `+` in the 3rd and `CG` in the 6th column?

Comment: @MartijnPieters in file2, there are 8 columns but I am matching with 4 columns only, and there are approximately 2 million rows.

Comment: @kashiff007: out of those 2 million, how many match those criteria I mentioned? You don't use all 2 million.

Comment: I have to reads all 2 million lines because I do not know which row has matching criteria. It may be none or may be 1000, and if 1000 can not be necessarily from consecutive rows.

Comment: @kashiff007: I'm trying to get a ballpark from you. I know you are not using all 2 million rows. I'm working on a solution and getting a percentage or rough count can help me help you. Please run a quick script that counts how many rows match in your current file. It **doesn't matter** if they are consecutive.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to store the list representation of rows in `f2` into your output file? `lt` is a list, `lt.append(line2)` appends strings, and `str(lt)` produces a string with `[` and `]` characters at the start and end, and `'` or `"` characters around each 'line'. There are more efficient ways of storing that information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for asking this with explanation. its approximately ranging from 0 to 100. I am using dict for efficient storing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a O(N * M) loop over file I/O, that is very slow indeed. You can improve per-line processing by using the `csv` module to do parse each line into a list for you in C code, and drop the redundant `str()` calls (you already have strings), but your real problem is the nested loop.

You can easily avoid that loop. There may be millions of rows in your second file, but you already filter those rows to a **much** smaller number, between 0 and 100. That can be trivially held in memory and accessed per `s0` value in next to no time.

Store the information from each row in a dictionary; pre-parse the 2nd column integer, and store the whole row for output to the output file in the `lt` list:

```
import csv

# dictionary mapping row[0] to a list of (int(row[1]), line) values
report_map = {}

with open("../BS_Forward.fastq_bismark_pe.CX_report.txt", 'r', newline='') as report:
    reader = csv.reader(report, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] != "+" or row[5] != "CG":
            continue
        key, value = row[0], int(row[1])
        line = '\t'.join(row)
        report_map.setdefault(key, []).append((value, line))
```

After building that dictionary, you can look up matches against `s0` in O(1) time, so your loop over `f1` is a straightforward loop with a cheap operation for each row. When you find a match in the `report_map` dictionary, you only need to loop over the associated list to filter on the `row[1]` integer values:

```
with open("../../Reapeat_analysis/FIMO/fimo_out/fimo.gff", 'r', newline='') as fimo, \
     open("output_sample_CG+.txt", 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fimo, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimeter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        s0 = row[0]
        s1, s2 = map(int, row[3:5])
        if s0 not in report_map:
            continue
        lt = [r for i, r in report_map[s0] if s1 <= i <= s2]
        writer.writerow(["{}-{}:{}".format(s1, s2, s0), len(lt), str(lt)])
```

I strongly recommend *against* storing the whole line from the `BS_Forward.fastq_bismark_pe.CX_report.txt` file, certainly not as a Python [printable representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). I don't know how you plan to use that data, but at least consider using JSON to serialise the `lt` list to a string representation. JSON is readable by other platforms and faster to parse back into a suitable Python data structure.

Comment: I am grateful that you teach me file hadelling with dictionary. I have to play with it to get familiar.